# how can i get a image background with white contain space on it as shown below in screenshot

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Screenshot]
Here you can see that there is a background and above it there is a white layer on which contain are given. screenshot is of a website but i want to give that effect on my app. any help will be of great use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/yourBackgroudImage"/>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:bacground="@color/white"
         android:layout_margin="20dp">

         <!--your code inside white backgroud layout goes here-->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `RelativeLayout` which helps you to stack your views above each other,then provide a margin to the top layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/backgroundimage"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!--Add Data here as required-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```